# Is there any information on what happened to Vector?

Tags: despicable-me

In *Despicable Me*, after being defeated, Vector is shown standing on the moon wearing a space helmet of some sort. Is he, after that scene, dead, elaborately explained into surviving, or just never mentioned again?

**Is there any information, from the director/writers or official stuff based on the film, as to what happened to him after this scene?**

Comment: Vector reappears in the video game Minion Rush. The game is apparently set after Despicable Me 3 and Vector appears as a boss level baddie. Does that count?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the "[AVL Files](https://bbfc.co.uk/releases/despicable-me-3-avl-files-video)", provided as an extra on the Despicable Me 3 Bluray, Vector is *alive* on the moon. This is, however, presented in the form of an urban legend.

> *"At last report he was still stranded on the lunar surface. And it's said that on a clear night, looking through a telescope, Vector is still visible as a roaming orange dot"*

It's worth noting that the Anti-Villain League do consider Vector to still be alive ("***Active***") as opposed to presumed dead.